# Validating URL params when using the FrameworkExtraBundle to get an entity in Symfony 3.4 application

Tags: php, symfony, routes, php-7, symfony-3.4

Is there a way I can validate the URL params being passed in to my route?

If I try and hit this route with `/resume-session/crmpicco1872/kdsjfslk/rfc/three` for example Symfony throws a HTTP 500 because i'm giving it an owner id of "crmpicco1872".

Is there a way I can more gracefully fail on this action, i.e redirect elsewhere, or is it assumed that the params coming in are clean and validated?

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/resume-session/{ownerId}/{courseId}/{position}/{stage}",
 *      name = "resume_session",
 * )
 * @Entity("person", expr="repository.find(ownerId)")
 * @Entity("course", expr="repository.find(courseId)")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Person $person
 * @param Course $course
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function resumeSessionAction(Request $request, Person $person, Course $course): Response
```